# threading.Timer eventually stops working

Tags: python, multithreading, timer

I'm trying to call a function every 3 seconds, lasting forever in Python 3.4 but eventually the Timer just stops working. Sometimes it's after 5 minutes and sometimes 5 hours, is there some other way of doing this?

```
import threading

i = 0
def f():
    global i
    print('Tick {}'.format(i))
    i += 1
    threading.Timer(3, f).start()

threading.Timer(3, f).start()
```

edit: I forgot to mention the program never exits, it just no longer calls the function and sits around doing nothing.

Comment: Is the posted code supposed to be a simplified illustration, or is that the actual code that can be run to reproduce the problem? Your approach of running a timer with the next invocation of `f` seems exception-unsafe. If an exception happens in a run of `f`, the next iteration will never be scheduled. Maybe that's what's happening in your case?

Comment: The code is a simplified case but does have the same problem. And if there's an exception somewhere should I not see the exception printed out? Oops I seem to have left out a major part of the problem, the program never exits, it just doesn't continue calling the function.

Comment: Is there any possible path the code could take that would skip setting the `Timer` again? It might be worth sticking the whole function in a `try`/`finally` block, and putting the `threading.Timer(3, f).start()` call in the `finally` block.

Comment: You should see the exception printed out - unless someone catches it, of course. If you can reproduce the problem with the above code sample, you might want to [report the bug](http://bugs.python.org/) to Python developers.

Comment: I am seeing the same problem after six hours. Did you find a solution for this?